# Can 'numberposts' be passed in the URL query string?

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string

I'm running into circles trying to set up a simple rewrite rule, and thought I'd run the question by some of the rewrite experts here.

I have a custom post type, "mealplan", and I'm trying to implement a basic url rewrite where visitng `site.com/mealplan/current` will take the visitor to the most recent post of type "mealplan".

I've tried using several variants on this rule:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('mealplan/current', 
  'index.php?post_type=mealplan&numberposts=1&orderby=date&order=DESC', 
  'top' );
```

... but I can't seem to get either the 'numberposts' or the 'posts_per_page' parameters to do anything in the query string like that.  It just goes straight to the archive page with the default number of posts per page.

This does what I want:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$current_mealplan = get_posts( array(
  'post_type'=>'mealplan',
  'numberposts'=>1,
  'orderby'=>'date',
  'order'=>'DESC' ) );
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('mealplan/current', 
  'index.php?post_type=mealplan&post_id='.$current_mealplan[0]->ID, 
  'top');
```

...but at the cost of an additional query and a potential flush rules on every page load. Even if I optimize this by saving the current post ID in an option that's updated on `update_post` (so rules only have to be flushed when they change), this feels like unnecessary work that could be avoided if I could only get the url parameters above to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `numberposts` is not actually a query variable. It's just turned into `posts_per_page` in `get_posts()` before the query is run. `posts_per_page` is a private query var, which means you can't run it in the query string. A possible solution would be to register a custom query variable (let's say `'latest_mealplan'` and add that variable to the rewrite rule (e.g. `index.php?post_type=mealplan&orderby=date&order=DESC&latest_mealplan=1`).

Then, hook into `'parse_request'`, which passes the `$wp` object to the callback. From there, it's just a matter of setting the parameter:

```
if( !empty( $wp->query_vars['latest_mealplan'] ) ){
  $wp->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 1;
  add_filter( 'template_include', create_function( '$a', 'return locate_template(array("single-mealplan.php"));' ) );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot... I was almost there, but I was thrown by the syntax of that hook... I wasn't familiar with the context of the `do_action_ref_array` call. So now my url rewrite shows only one post, but its still using the archive template, not the "single-mealplan.php" template. I've tried adding  `$wp->is_singular = $wp->is_single = true;`, but I think its too late. Is there an earlier hook I can use, before the template is set?

Comment: `$wp` doesn't have the value for `is_single()`, that'd be `$wp_query->is_single`. But you don't even need to touch that. Just add code to filter the template directly. I'll edit the code above to reflect that.

Comment: Actually they are both query variables, they're just not **public** query variables, unlike cat, tag, page, etc.. (meta_key would be an example of another **private** query variable).